# Identifying PHP unused variables

Tags: php, eclipse, variables, eclipse-pdt

I have seen the below question and was wondering if there is something like it for [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

Also, how can I make sure that this kind of errors gets thrown into my trigger error function, so that I can write it to a log.

*[How can I identify PHP unused variables (in Emacs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534176/identifying-php-unused-variables-in-emacs)*

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it can report unused variables, but [**PHP_CodeSniffe**](http://pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSniffer)r is nice when it comes to detecting problems in PHP source code.

Still, it's a command-line tool, and it's not integrated in Eclipse PDT...

As a side note:

- Unused variables *(i.e., variables that get assigned a value, and are never used again)* are not a problem in PHP -- so, they are not reported as an error nor anything by PHP itself
- On the other hand, undeclared variables *(i.e., variables that are being read from, while no value was assigned to them before)* are not that good -- so, they are reported a notices by the PHP engine.

The post you are linking to is talking about the second kind, and not the first one.

To get undeclared/uninitialized variables reported by the PHP engine:

- You have to enable [**`error_reporting`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting), and configure it so it report **`E_NOTICE`**
- You can then have those reports either:

  - displayed in the generated page (nice when developping) : [**`display_errors`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)
  - or logged in a file: [**`log_errors`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors)

But, here too, this is not integrated in Eclipse -- and I've never seen a tool that would parse the PHP error log, and push the notices to Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

The [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE (I switched from Eclipse [PDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Development_Tools) last month) identifies and shows warning about unused and uninitialized methods, variables, etc.

Comment: I switched from Netbeans 8.2 to Eclipse Oxygen. I go back to Netbeans due to this missing feature.. Neatbeans show unused & uninitiated variables out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) Eclipse yet?
According to my colleagues it is a pretty handy tool.

Comment: PMD is AFAIK only for Java, not PHP but a great tool indeed

Comment: From *https://pmd.github.io/#about*: *"PMD is a source code analyzer. It finds common programming flaws like unused variables, empty catch blocks, unnecessary object creation, and so forth. It supports Java, JavaScript, Salesforce.com Apex and Visualforce, PLSQL, Apache Velocity, XML, XSL."*

Answer (score 0):

Install [PDT Extensions](http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/).

From the Eclipse ([PDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Development_Tools)) main menu, select *Help* → *Install New Software*.

Then enter the above URL in the 'Work with' edit box. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>. Check the 'PDT Extensions' checkbox. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>...